# SQL Server replication tool

Tags: windows, database, sql-server

I'm looking for a Windows tool (preferably installable as a windows service) for periodic database synchronization.

Once every X minutes it should connect to `Source` SQL Server database, check for any new objects there (tables, new rows in these tables, views, etc.) and transfer these objects to the `Destination` SQL Server database.

The type of the tool (gratis or paid, open- or closed-source) does not matter.

Comment: SQL Server has replication built in.

Comment: You don't want two-way synchronization right? If it is only one-way it is replication/mirroring which is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to post a similar thread when I stumbled upon your question...
Since you got no answers so far, I am leaving here the outcome of my research:

- [Symmetric DS](https://www.symmetricds.org) (open source, written in Java)
- [Microsoft Synch Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490616) (there is one article there that may be of your interest: [SQL Server to SQL Azure Synchronization](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-server-to-sql-azure-synchronization.aspx))

Comment: Please give much more detail about each solution, please see http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality I suggest posting one answer per solution, so that people can vote for both separately.